# Pointed/Aimed the gun at

Tags: word-choice, difference

She pulled out a gun and pointed/aimed it at him.

Is there any significant difference between these or are they interchangeable here?

Is there a difference if it's pointed/aimed from short or long distance?

Comment: _Aimed_ makes it clear that there was an intention to shoot, or at least a threat.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of precision.  If you point a gun at someone, you're not putting in a lot of effort to be accurate with it.  At short range that may not matter, and so the words would become more similar in use, but at a longer range then "aimed" emphasises an intent for accuracy.